# Output from numpy.matrix_power differs from formulaic way of solving

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I am supposed to use python to solve a Matrix A^1000. I have tried numpy's built in matrix_power function to compute the output, but when I try to compute the result step by step according to the formula P*(D^1000) *P^-1 , I get an incomplete result. I am trying to figure out if my precision options are just too tight or if I am doing something else wrong completely

I have tried the matrix_power function to definitely get the result I want.  But I need to be able to show how the calculation is done, and when I do so, I get an incomplete result

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=6)   # set the precision of the output
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True) # suppress the use of scientific notation
from numpy import diag, allclose, corrcoef
from numpy.random import randint, randn
from numpy.linalg import eig, matrix_rank, inv, cholesky, qr, norm, matrix_power
from sympy import Matrix, init_printing, matrix2numpy

A = np.array([[0.9,0.15,0.25],[0.075,0.8,0.25],[0.025,0.05,0.5]])
A

#python way
A_1000 = matrix_power(A,1000)
A_1000

D , P = eig(A)
P * np.diag(D**1000) * np.linalg.inv(p)
```

Comment: For numpy arrays, `*` is *element-wise* multiplication. If you are using Python 3,  change `P * np.diag(D**1000) * np.linalg.inv(p)` to `P @ np.diag(D**1000) @ np.linalg.inv(p)`.

Comment: I'd make my comment an answer, but questions like this have been asked many times, so I'm sure that, on some level, it is a duplicate question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. that makes sense. Thank you for the help regardless. Perhaps I was not searching the corrext question

Comment: *"Perhaps I was not searching the corrext question"*  Not necessarily. There are probably many questions where it turns out that the problem was using `*` instead of `@`, but if you don't know that is the problem, it would be difficult to find such a duplicate.